# Notepad++ Wildcard problems in search and replace

Tags: notepad++

i got an insanely high amount of id's. They are all like ([ID]) or ([NEW ID])
is there a way to take them and put them in replace with:"" with wildcards or so?
I use notepad++

Thank you for your time!
-Rick

Sample input:

in the find field "123"
Replace field : ([ID])

(The ID must become a wildcard so in google language, it would've been this: ([*])

Edit:

```
INT([Aangelijnd Op De Rug])+INT([Aanlijning Voor Harnas Bereikbaar])+INT([Afzetting Van Werkplek Indien Van Toepassing Oke])+INT([Als Het Werk Langer Duurt Dan Gepland Op Vergunning])+INT([Ander Gereedschap Materiaal In Orde])
```

those are only like 5% of the id's I have to switch to another formula.  Every thing between the tags `"([   ])"` is and ID. And i need them all to replace this:

```
"(-*-*)"
```

In the formula:

```
=IF(OR(INT(-*-*)=2;INT(-*-*)=2;INT(-*-*)=2;INT(-*-*)=2;INT(-*-*)=2;INT(-*-*)=2;INT(-*-*)=2;INT(-*-*)=2;INT(-*-*)=2
```

Comment: Please, give a sample input and expected result.

Comment: @M42 Edited the questions ^^

Comment: It isn't so clear... Give an extract (few lines) of the original text and expected result.

Comment: @M42 Edited the post, better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure to well understand, but is that what you want?

Find what: `INT\(\[[^]]+\]\)\+`
Replace with: `INT\(-*-*\)=2;`